# Tkinter, pause after select Combobox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a ttk.Combobox. After user select one value, the drop down list will disappear and pause for one second before showing the result.

I tried x.after(1000) on several different location. It will be either a pause when GUI opens or a pause on drop down list (i.e the drop down list will not disappear until 1000 ms).

Is it possible to pause after the value is selected and drop down disappeared?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App():

    def __init__(self, root):

        # Main Frame
        frame = ttk.Frame(root)
        frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='WESN')

        self.test_lf = ttk.LabelFrame(frame, text='Test')
        self.test_lf.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, sticky='WE')

        self.selection = tk.StringVar()
        self.selection.trace('w', self.result)

        options = ttk.Combobox(self.test_lf, textvariable=self.selection, width=10)
        options['values'] = ('A', 'B', 'C')
        options.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='WE', columnspan=2)
        # options.after(1000)    # Pause when open

        result_label = ttk.Label(self.test_lf, text='Result:')
        result_label.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')

    def result(self, *args):
        selection_value=self.selection.get()
        selection_result = ttk.Label(self.test_lf, text=selection_value)
        selection_result.grid(column=1, row=2)
        # selection_result.after(1000) # Pause on drop down list

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Sample')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, you just need to give the `after` method the code to run to show the result.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, root) # this class is itself the main frame

        self.test_lf = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Test')
        self.test_lf.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, sticky='WE')

        self.selection = tk.StringVar()
        self.selection.trace('w', self.result)

        options = ttk.Combobox(self.test_lf, textvariable=self.selection, width=10)
        options['values'] = ('A', 'B', 'C')
        options.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='WE', columnspan=2)

        result_label = ttk.Label(self.test_lf, text='Result:')
        result_label.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='W')

        self.selection_result = ttk.Label(self.test_lf)
        self.selection_result.grid(column=1, row=2)

    def result(self, *args):
        self.after(1000, self.show_result)

    def show_result(self, *args):
        selection_value=self.selection.get()
        self.selection_result.config(text=selection_value)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Sample')
app = App(root)
app.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='WESN')
root.mainloop()
```

I also made some other improvements to your code that you should use, like subclassing Frame and updating a variable, not creating a new one, when something changes.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solve my problem. And I appreciate your advice.